# Django,method POST, return render context

Tags: django, post, context

Объясните мне в чем дело, это не работает! Принты всё выводят но предпоследняя строка не выполняется, а выполняется последняя и ошибок нет! А если последнюю убрать то он пишет: didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. Не пойму в чем проблема, в примерах аналогичного кода всё так и всё работает...

```
def profile(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print("**post**")
            name = request.POST['user']
            print(name)//OK
            user=User.objects.filter(username=name)
            print(user)//OK
            profile=Profile.objects.get(user=user)
            nick=profile.user
            print(nick)//ОК
            return render(request, 'profile.html', {'nick':nick})//НЕ работает
        return render(request, 'reg.html')//Работает
```

Comment: Задача элементарная, если метод POST то мне надо отдать один шаблон, если НЕ метод POST другой шаблон, НО по какой-то причине если метод POST то джанга отказывается отдавать шаблон!